# Parsing XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Is it necessary to use the second line here?

```
  $("message",xml).each(function(id) {
    message = $("message",xml).get(id);
    msgID = $("msgID",message).text();
```

Isn't there some kind of 'this' keyword to eliminate the second line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('message', xml).each(function() {
    var msgID = $(this).find('msgID').text();
}
```

Assuming this structure:

```
<root>
    <message>
        <msgID>123</msgID>
    </message>
    <message>
        <msgID>234</msgID>
    </message>
    <message>
        <msgID>345</msgID>
    </message>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you just write this.find, without using the jQuery symbol and parentheses?

Comment: @Michael No, because the `this` keyword refers to the XML node object (or whatever it's name is), but `find()` is a jQuery method and it can only be called on jQuery objects.

Comment: well, it's a good practice to capture `$(this)` in a variable. Like `var $this = $(this);`...

Comment: @Reigel I've done some benchmarking and on my machine it takes 0,00021ms to execute `$(this)`. Performance-wise, it's not an issue. http://jsfiddle.net/aFUKH/

Comment: hehe I'm not saying it's an issue. :) Just a *good practice*. http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects

Answer (score 1):

When you're in [an `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), `this` will represent the current item in the iteration.

The `.each()` also gives you 2 parameters. The first is the current index number of the iteration, and the second is the item in the iteration, same as `this`.

```
$("message",xml).each(function( idx, val ) {
    // in here, "this" is the current "message" node in the iteration
    // "i" is the current index in the iteration
    // "val" is the same as "this"
});
```

When you do `$("message",xml)`, you are looking for `"message"` nodes that are *nested* under the nodes at the top of `xml`. If any were found, the `.each()` will iterate over them.